# How to render 500(Internal Server Error) page using an erb instead of a static HTML in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to have errors render a 500.html.erb file instead of the 500.html page in the public folder? I want to be able to use partials and make the page dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the following approach.

1.Create a controller like `app/controllers/http_errors_controller.rb`

```
class HttpErrorsController < ApplicationController
   def internal_server_error
     render(:status => 500)
   end
end
```

2.Have a corresponding view - `app/views/http_errors/internal_server_error.html.erb`

3.Configure your routes

```
match "/500", :to => "http_errors#internal_server_error", :via => :all
```

4.Configure Rails to pick up your views instead of the default ones in the public folder. This you can achieve by adding the below line to `config/application.rb`

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

5.Remove the corresponding static files in the pubilc folder. `public/500.html` in your case.

For more on this, and its drawbacks, refer https://mattbrictson.com/dynamic-rails-error-pages

Also, there is this gem that addresses such problems stated in the above link that will acheive what you are trying to do : https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler

Though, I would suggest against using a gem for something as simple as this.